# When will Hund's rules fail?

Tags: angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals

I heard someone mentioned that [Hund's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules) do not always work.

Looking at atomic spectrum:
(https://qudev.phys.ethz.ch/phys4/PHYS4_lecture10v1_2page.pdf  page 10 Hg spectrum) How could singlet (with multiplicity 1) has lower energy than triplet (with multiplicity 3)?

When will hunds' fail and how do we work with them?

Comment: I think you might be mis-understanding the Hg atom.  In the ground state the 6s and 5d levels are full, so all orbitals are doubly occupied and it is a singlet.  The next level up is the 6p.  So when the atom is excited there will be two unpaired electrons when one enters 6p, so the state will be a triplet.

Comment: Try asking a similar question about platinum  :-o